# I have a problem with a promise inside a function and a forEach method

Tags: javascript, object, promise

I have these water names and I want that putting an input with a water name, the promise will return me a result. The problem is that it doesn't return anything, how can I fix it?

```js
const water = [
  { nome: "Sant'anna", inStore: true },
  { nome: "Levissima", inStore: false },
  { nome: "Lete", inStore: true },
];

let inStoreTrue = [];
let inStoreFalse = [];
water.forEach(({ nome, inStore }) => {
  if (inStore === true) {
    inStoreTrue.push({ nome });
  } else {
    inStoreFalse.push({ nome });
  }
});

function checkWater(enter) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (enter === inStoreTrue) {
      resolve("la tua acqua è disponibile");
    } else if (enter === inStoreFalse) {
      reject("La tua acqua non è disponibile");
    }
  });
}

let prom = checkWater("Sant'anna");
prom
  .then((risultato) => {
    console.log(risultato);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with checking `enter === inStoreTrue` and enter === inStoreFalse

`inStoreTrue` and `inStoreFalse` are arrays. So you cannot simply equate a string with an array. You have to check whether the string is there in the array with some array methods. I used `Array.some` for that.

```js
const water = [
  { nome: "Sant'anna", inStore: true },
  { nome: "Levissima", inStore: false },
  { nome: "Lete", inStore: true },
];

let inStoreTrue = [];
let inStoreFalse = [];
water.forEach(({ nome, inStore }) => {
  if (inStore === true) {
    inStoreTrue.push({ nome });
  } else {
    inStoreFalse.push({ nome });
  }
});

function checkWater(enter) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    if (inStoreTrue.some((item) => item.nome === enter)) {
      resolve("la tua acqua è disponibile");
    } else if (inStoreFalse.some((item) => item.nome === enter)) {
      reject("La tua acqua non è disponibile");
    }
  });
}

let prom = checkWater("Sant'anna");
prom
  .then((risultato) => {
    console.log(risultato);
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log(err);
  });
```

Comment: @kas Please approve this answer is this is what you are looking for. Happy to have an upvote aswell.